# Ownership issue with Clang frontend API

Tags: c++, clang

I'm using the Clang C++ API. As the API does not use smart pointers correctly, I've struggled with ownership. I stomped on all the issues I found so far on my own, but this one is vexing me. When the code executes, I get an access violation. I'm fairly certain it's a double delete, but since the documentation is nonexistent, I've got little idea where to look. Fortunately, the reproducing program is rather short. Any suggestions?

```
#define _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#pragma warning(push, 0)

#include <clang/CodeGen/CodeGenAction.h>
#include <clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h>
#include <clang/Sema/Lookup.h>
#include <clang/Lex/Preprocessor.h>
#include <clang/AST/ASTContext.h>
#include <clang/AST/Mangle.h>
#include <clang/Frontend/TextDiagnosticPrinter.h>
#include <clang/Basic/TargetInfo.h>
#include <clang/Sema/Sema.h>
#include <clang/Sema/SemaConsumer.h>
#include <clang/Sema/CodeCompleteConsumer.h>
#include <llvm/LLVMContext.h>
#include <llvm/Support/DataTypes.h>
#include <llvm/Module.h>
#include <llvm/Support/Host.h>

#pragma warning(pop)

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    llvm::LLVMContext c;
    llvm::Module m("", c);
    clang::EmitLLVMOnlyAction emit(&c);
    emit.setLinkModule(&m);
    clang::CompilerInstance CI;

    std::string errors;
    llvm::raw_string_ostream error_stream(errors);
    clang::DiagnosticOptions diagopts;
    clang::TextDiagnosticPrinter printer(error_stream, &diagopts);
    llvm::IntrusiveRefCntPtr<clang::DiagnosticIDs> diagids(new clang::DiagnosticIDs);
    clang::DiagnosticsEngine engine(diagids, &diagopts, &printer, false);
    CI.setDiagnostics(&engine);

    CI.createFileManager();
    CI.createSourceManager(CI.getFileManager());

    llvm::raw_null_ostream empty;
    clang::PrintingCodeCompleteConsumer print(CodeCompleteOptions(), empty);        

    clang::TargetOptions target;
    target.Triple = llvm::sys::getDefaultTargetTriple();
    CI.setTarget(clang::TargetInfo::CreateTargetInfo(engine, &target));

    CI.createPreprocessor();
    CI.createASTContext();

    clang::SemaConsumer* cons = new clang::SemaConsumer();

    CI.setASTConsumer(cons);    
    CI.createSema(clang::TranslationUnitKind::TU_Complete, &print);
    cons->InitializeSema(CI.getSema());

    clang::FrontendInputFile f("header", clang::InputKind::IK_CXX, true);
    emit.BeginSourceFile(CI, f);
    emit.Execute();
    emit.EndSourceFile();
    emit.takeModule();
    clang::LookupResult lr(CI.getSema(), clang::DeclarationName(CI.getPreprocessor().getIdentifierInfo("function")), clang::SourceLocation(), clang::Sema::LookupNameKind::LookupOrdinaryName);
    auto result = CI.getSema().LookupName(lr, CI.getSema().TUScope);

    std::string temp;
    llvm::raw_string_ostream out(temp);
    CI.getASTContext().createMangleContext()->mangleName(lr.getFoundDecl(), out);
    auto fun = m.getFunction(temp);

    std::cout << fun->getName().str();

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Also, did I mention that if I change it so that the file actually exists, even if it's a trivial program, Clang fails with an access violation whilst executing the action, even before the previous one in `EndSourceFile`. Whyyyyyy.

Comment: Have you tried running it under valgrind?

Comment: Remove the delete's just to see if the problem goes away?

Comment: I notice you're using `auto`, which means that you're using C++11.

How did you build your clang libraries? Did you build them with a C++11 compiler/standard library?

Comment: @brianbeuning: I don't delete anything.

Comment: @MarshallClow: I did indeed. I built them with the exact same compiler I'm using- VS 2012.

Comment: You will have to step through the code. `auto result = CI.getSema().LookupName(lr, CI.getSema().TUScope);` This line for example could crash if `lr` does not have a name for example.

Comment: It does not get there. It crashes in `Execute`. I have managed to determine that the Preprocessor is a bad pointer, but why this would occur is quite beyond me. The Clang interface is so, so bad when it comes to ownership.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually solved this by skipping the entire Frontend, as that's mostly where all of the dodgy ownership lies, and simply calling the functions I need myself.